Particles to add to the end of a vocabulary item to facilitate learning the distinction between flat and final accents
What particles can one append to the end of a Japanese word to make it easier to learn whether it has a flat (平板 heiban, …H(-H)) or a final (尾高 odaka, …H(-L)) accent?
Background: To learn the gender of French nouns, one can just prepend an imaginary article ("le"/"un" for masculine, "la"/"une" for feminine) instead of using a gender mnemonic. For example, instead of somehow memorizing {"soleil" is masculine and means "sun", and "lune" is feminine and means "moon"}, one can just recite "le soleil – sun" and "la lune – moon" upon each repetition of the vocabulary item and learn the gender associations that way.
I'm looking for a similar strategy for Japanese pitch accent, to be used for cases in which the choice of flat/平板 vs final/尾高 isn't obvious from the word's citation form. That is, I'm looking for a set of particles (perhaps one particle x for each part of speech) where I can simply learn (via vocalization) either of

[はし(x)]{LHHHH}
[はし(x)]{LHLLL}

instead of trying to memorize the more abstract

[はし]{LH} and {a following unaccented morpheme would have pitch H}
[はし]{LH} and {a following unaccented morpheme would have pitch L}

(depending on which applies to any given lexeme). If anyone's interested, I presently use the following respective notations in my vocabulary deck: はし￫, はしꜜ.
Is there one particle which can be appended to everything? Or would it be better to use different ones depending on the part of speech? In either case, which could one use?
Being a beginner, I find it difficult to come up with a strategy that is comprehensive. For instance, いいえ ("no") is indicated in learning resources as [いいえ(x)]{LHHLLL}, but I don't see how I can meaningfully append a particle here.

To be clear, you consider speaking the word(s) aloud to be important to this study method?

@KarlKnechtel I wouldn't say "important", as that might imply "essential", but my method is intended as a handy mnemonic trick.

As I used in my past answer, the final particle ね would be the best for this purpose. It is literally able to be attached to any syntactic word boundary (文節), without semantic preference, so you can ask a speaker to demonstrate almost anytime. Of course, it does not change the accent pattern of the previous chunk.

はしね{LHL} (< 橋)
はしね{LHH} (< 端)

The topic particle は could be a good choice of a semantically neutral particle if the word form is noun or nominal.
By the way, I think いいえ is only 尾高 when it is a noun ("(a) nay") or closing a sentence. Otherwise as an interjection, it is 平板.

いいえ{LHH}(ね{L})。
いいえ{LHH}(ね{H})、私はペンではありません。


Interestingly 〜は and 〜ね will behave differently on a very small set of words. E.g., (adv) だいたい￣ vs だいた＼いは vs だいた＼いだ vs だいたいね￣. Though not all speakers do the drop for は. Also (adv) きのう￣、きの＼うは、きの＼うだ、きのうね￣ for something more consistent among speakers. It guess for the purpose of the OP they might actually want to learn with 〜は attached because that is exceptional, while 〜ね is more consistent  Hard to say though

@DariusJahandarie Good point. This page would be useful for understanding: 東京方言の「昨日類」（アクセントと音節の関係）. Btw I think it is きのうね{LHLL} if used as a noun.

What do you mean by 文節? Google Translate shows me the meanings "clause", "phrase", "paragraph". I earlier thought you meant "constituent", but the Japanese Wikipedia translates this as 構成素.

@LoverofStructure Good question... I don't think I can explain it without being tautology. It is a widely recognized unit in Japanese grammatical theories, deemed as a fully morphologically synthesized chunk or a syntactic minimal unit. So if Japanese is spelled like Turkish, the unit would be spelled in a single orthographic word.

Okay, so I would just say "word (incl particles attached to it)" – correct?

@LoverofStructure Yes, more or less in a general linguistic term.

This may be a good opportunity to point out that there is a difference between "orthographic word" and "linguistic word" in English (eg "swimming pool" is a single linguistic word).

You're probably still better off remembering the "abstract" information like here:

instead of trying to memorize the more abstract

はし and {a following unaccented morpheme would have pitch H}
はし and {a following unaccented morpheme would have pitch L}

Since that's where the pitch of the particle is deriving its pitch from. There's also cases of certain particles like の removing the accent in words, but you would still need to know the underlying PA pattern for normal contexts. So while

はし and {a following unaccented morpheme would have pitch H}
はし and {a following unaccented morpheme would have pitch L}

Sounds like a lot, you simply replace it with 平板 or 尾高 and you already do this for the other patterns so this is no different as well. Plus there are resources like PA dictionaries and plugins that automatically color code vocabulary on websites and flashcards to lessen this burden.
So unless you are trying to practice output or a specific phrase or something where you mess up the distinction between 平板 and 尾高 even though you know the difference. On a word-level basis as you go learning new vocabulary, you simply tag on one or more of the 4 PA patterns to that word and so while it's going to take a long time and be hard, it's simple process.
So basically assuming you already use this "abstract" process for memorizing 頭高 and 中高 with no trouble, it's the same idea for 平板 and 尾高.

I am not sure what you mean by saying that I "already do this for the other patterns". For a word like 事務所 (office) I would just memorize [じむしょ]{LHLL} (marked as じむꜜしょ in my vocabulary deck); here the pitch contour of the lexeme's citation form encodes the nature/position of the pitch accent, which wouldn't be so for [はし]{LH} without a following particle.

I'm not sure what it's called but there is a notation that marks 尾高 in a similar manner but without the particle. The line is like notched downwards.

Something like this. https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/search/index/sortprefix:accent/narabi1:kata_asc/narabi2:accent_asc/narabi3:mola_asc/yure:visible/curve:invisible/details:invisible/limit:20/word:%E3%81%AF%E3%81%97

You could also just mark it as 尾高 and not do all the notation stuff.

I have no trouble imagining abstract information (unlike some learners), but the whole point of the question is to be able to verbalize it as well, to aid in memorization. That is, upon each repetition, I say (or imagine) [はしx]{LHH} or [はしx]{LHL}. For nouns I can just use x=は, but this particle presumably doesn't work for all parts of speech.
